# Is Kafka a Message Queue or a Message Broker?

Tags: apache-kafka, message-queue, publish-subscribe, messagebroker

After going through a couple of articles explaining the difference between **Message Queues** and **Message Brokers**, I'm quite confused as to whether **Kafka** is a Message Queue or a Message Broker.

`The main difference that I know is that Message Queue offer two types of models:`

1. **Point to Point Messaging**
2. **Publisher-Subscriber Model**

whereas **Message Brokers** offer only the **Publisher-Subscriber** model.

In the case of Kafka, my understanding is that it offers Publisher-Subscriber Model.

Hence, I'm quite confused. Can someone please help me here ??

Comment: Does it really matter? It's a distributed log with temporarily persistent queues hosted by servers called brokers

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm clear about the working and stuff. Just got too much confused because these two terms are used interchangeably a lot. 

So you mean to say both these things mean the same ?

Comment: A Kafka server is a broker. A Kafka topic can be used as a first-in-first-out (FIFO) data-structure, which is a queue. Producers (or publishers, as you call them) enqueue, and consumers subscribe. However, like many "message queues", Kafka does not actually "remove" any elements coming out of it, so there is no proper "dequeue" action. Clients are still "point-to-point" with a server in-between

Answer (score 0):

Kafka can replace Message Queues (MQ), such as RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ for some implementations, but it is definitely not MQ. So this one is off the table.

> A **message queue** consists of two components: a **message broker** and a client. The message broker is responsible for receiving and storing messages in a queue, and the client is responsible for sending and receiving messages from the broker.

from a Medium article [here](https://medium.com/@fullstacktips/mq-vs-kafka-which-messaging-system-is-right-for-your-distributed-system-692debae1033)

Therefore, calling Kafka a Message Broker will also be confusing and probably inaccurate.

What may be causing this confusion, is the fact that the main server type in a Kafka Cluster is called a **Broker**, but as stated it does not define Kafka and should not be used as a synonym for its name. Most sources that I have read refer to Kafka as a Distributed Event Streaming Platform.

On a personal note, Kafka for me is a category of its own, so should only be called Kafka.. Hope I answered your question.

Some additional sources to look into

1. [Kafka Intro](https://kafka.apache.org/intro) from Apache site
2. [Kafka Docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#introduction) from Apache site
3. Difference between Kafka and RabbitMQ from [Simplilearn](https://www.simplilearn.com/kafka-vs-rabbitmq-article)